# Google Authentication in Rails - "uninitialized constant GoogleAuthExample (NameError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-authentication

I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails?comments_page=1) on integrating Google Authentication into Rails apps. I've only been learning Ruby / Rails for a few weeks (though have some other programming experience) and have encountered an error while following the tutorial - not sure if it's something really obvious that I'm misunderstanding.

When I run try to start the server after following the instructions in the tutorial, I get:

```
"Exiting
/Users/adam/Code/rails_projects/quickcal/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant GoogleAuthExample (NameError)"
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Still not working after changing GoogleAuthExample to the name of my app...

```
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant QuickCal (NameError)
```

EDIT: SOLVED
Following on from previous edit, just had to change QuickCal to Quickcal - whoops!

Comment: Did you restart the server after running `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, has been restarted. I'm pretty sure I've got the right gems installed too

Comment: I'm just not sure what "GoogleAuthExample" is supposed to be referring too...

Comment: Is your application called GoogleAuthExample? else, you would rename this with your applications name

Comment: My app is called QuickCal - I tried changing it to that earlier and then I just got an error with that instead of GoogleAuthExample... :\

Comment: Try my answer  ? And please show us some code and all the errors that you get! (Always edit your question and append them to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you use your applications name where in that tutorial is `GoogleAuthExample`.

For example in your routes file:

```
Quickcal::Application.routes.draw do
  # place routes
end
```

Comment: config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant QuickCal (NameError)

Comment: Ah! Not QuickCal, but Quickcal - made the difference. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.